# Broken ZIF Lock on Mac Mini A1176

Tags: audio, mac-mini

I recently was upgrading my Mac Mini's failing hard drive when I accidentally removed the audio board ZIF Cable lock completely from the board. It can be alternatively "fixed" by buying a USB audio adapter, but it would be nice to have fully functional. Is it possible to be fixed or is it stuck this way permanently? Thanks in advance!

**Mac Mini 1.83GHz Core Duo 2GB ram Early 2006**

Answer (score 1):

Yes is can be fixed. All connectors on a logic board can be replaced with the correct tools. SMD Soldering station, hot air.  Find your local repair shop and they can most likely do it for you.